# awk print lines before while match INFO untill match ERROR

Tags: regex, shell, awk, ssh

I want to print lines before my /ERROR/ match. The lines to be printed should be all containing INFO untill the previous ERROR is found.

So If I had a file

```
ERROR this is an error
INFO error found on line 2
INFO error is due to something
ERROR this is another error
```

I want the /ERROR/ from `ERROR this is another error` to print

```
INFO error found on line 2
INFO error is due to something
ERROR this is another error
```

Anyone know?

Part of my current script:

```
/CRITICAL/ {
    print "\x1b[93;1m"
}
/ERROR/     {
   print "\x1b[37m"
}
/ERROR|EMERGENCY|CRITICAL/ {
    if (NR == n+1) print "";
    n = NR;
    print x;print
    print "\x1b[0m"
};{x=$0}'
```

Comment: Edit your question to provide a large sample input set including lines you do NOT want to match. Right now theres too many possible answers depending on what the rest of your file contains and what you want done with it. For example if a 3rd ERROR line existed should there be a blank line between the output segments or not? Don't answer that in a comment - edit your question to show more comprehensive input/output.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one liner:
`awk 'x;/ERROR/{x=1}' file`

Out:

```
INFO error found on line 2
INFO error is due to something
ERROR this is another error
```

Long version:

```
x;/ERROR/{
    x1=1;
    print
}
```

If "ERROR" is found x=1, if x is true we've already gone through that line, then we print until we pass that line again.

Or maybe this, I don't have very clear what output you need.

`awk '/ERROR/{x=1;next}/ERROR/{x=1}x'`

Out

```
INFO error found on line 2
INFO error is due to something
```